# How to avoid race condition in a microservice application

Tags: java

I have a microservice application written in Java that is 1 out of many applications that are part of the project.

So here is the situation.

1. There is a class lets say `X` that does all the handling related to this `X` and its properties. Basically the transformation of `X`.
2. Calls comes from the rest interface on lets say `RestResourceHandler`
3. Another call comes on kafka consumer lets say `KafkaResourceHandler`
4. DB related stuff is done using a DAO class Lets say `DAOHandler`

Here is what happens, both `RestResourceHandler` and `KafkaResourceHandler` call `X` object and do the transformation using the methods available in X and then both saves this `X` into the DB using the `DAOHandler` , the problem is while doing transformation both resource handlers does some checking on properties of `X` and if its not as per expectation race conditions happens .

for example if rest resource is expecting `X.a=1` before storing to DB but till the time the request lands,  `X.a =2` was already done and saved in db by kafka resource .

So basically I need a streamlining mechanism so that processing happens sequentially

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can possibly do this is to put all the incoming requests on a kafka topic partitioned by the resourceId. That way, when you process these requests.. they will always be in sequence and you can avoid race condition.